# Submitting web form from python and saving results

Tags: python, html, form-submit, python-requests

I would like to access an online calculator from my python code. I have read the replies to similar questions, but couldn't come up with something that works. The following code is able to access the webpage and copy its contents, but I can't figure out how to submit something to the calculator and then save the result. I think the submission field is called M1value.

```
import requests
url = "http://www.numbertheory.org/php/classnopos.html"
payload = {'M1value':'7'}
r = requests.post(url, params=payload)
print(r.content)
```

Sorry if I'm making silly mistakes. I am new to this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Also I can't use mechanize since it's not supported by Python 3.

Comment: Have you asked this before? This is incredibly familiar.

Comment: Yeah I did, but this one is much more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are submitting to the wrong URL. If you look at the page source you see:

```
<FORM ACTION="classnopos.php" METHOD="POST">
```

You need to post to the `classnopos.php` URL instead:

```
url = "http://www.numbertheory.org/php/classnopos.php"
```

Using that URL and your code, I get the same result as using the form in my browser:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = "http://www.numbertheory.org/php/classnopos.php"
>>> payload = {'M1value':'7'}
>>> r = requests.post(url, params=payload)
>>> print(r.content)
<html>
<body bgcolor="FFFFCCC">

reduced forms of discriminant 28 corresponding to ideal classes<br>
[1]: (1,4,-3)<br>
x<sup>2</sup>-7*y<sup>2</sup>=-1 has no solution<br>
h(7) = 1<p>
<a href="./classnopos.html">Return to main page</a><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. Any idea how I could extract just '28' and '(1,4,-3)' from the output?

Comment: You'd have to use a regular expression for this, I fear.